# Get the window title data from a SwiftUI document based app

Tags: swiftui

Setting up a SwiftUI life cycle document based app is easy, especially for the title part -- it helps me handle all the file work I needed such as monitoring file name changes/move/deletion/editing status. However I want to hide it and create my own title, but I still want to take the advantage of these data. Is there a way that I can get them (file name, URL, edited status, etc) from somewhere? I tried to look for it in the FileDocument but it seems to be limited.

Thanks!